# PHP Mail message from database

Tags: php, email

I want the email message which contain the order details of customers.This code is ok for **only one order** but I don't know how to send message if customer select more than one products.
Here is my code :

```
include('connect.php');
if(!isset($_SESSION["id"]))
{
header("location:order_login.php");
}
$id=$_SESSION["id"];
$emp_name=$_SESSION['name'];

$result=$mysqli->query("select order_id from orders where user_id='$id' ORDER BY order_id desc limit 1"); 
$obj=$result->fetch_object();
$order_id=$obj->order_id;

$results=$mysqli->query("select * from order_details where order_id=$order_id");
        while($obj=$results->fetch_object())
      {

        $product_name=$obj->product_name;
        $product_code=$obj->product_code;
        $qty=$obj->qty;
        $subtotal=$obj->sub_total;


        }


$to="demo@gmail.com";
$bcc_mail="demo@gmail.com";
$subject= "Order Confirmation";

$message ='

<table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td>Name</td>
<td>Product Code</td>
<td>Quantity</td>
<td>Sub Total</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>'.$product_name.'</td>
<td>'.$product_code.'</td>
<td>'.$qty.'</td>
<td>'.$subtotal.'</td>
</tr>

</table>';

echo $message;

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: test@gmail.com'."\r\n";
$headers .= "Bcc: $bcc_mail\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

unset($_SESSION['products']);

?>
```

please check my code thanks.

Comment: Can you please specify how you store multiple orders in database?.if i guess than you must be storing multiple orders in order_details with same order id and if you do that then you can get all orders from order_details by your order id and please to improve your result don't fire separate query you can do this by  joins in single query.

Comment: yes i am storing multiple orders in order_details with same order id

Answer (score 1):

You should create a new `tr` section for each product:

```
include('connect.php');
if(!isset($_SESSION["id"]))
{
    header("location:order_login.php");
}
$id=$_SESSION["id"];
$emp_name=$_SESSION['name'];

$result=$mysqli->query("select order_id from orders where user_id='$id' ORDER BY order_id desc limit 1"); 
$obj=$result->fetch_object();
$order_id=$obj->order_id;   

$to="demo@gmail.com";
$bcc_mail="demo@gmail.com";
$subject= "Order Confirmation";

$message ='

<table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Product Code</td>
    <td>Quantity</td>
    <td>Sub Total</td>
</tr>';

$results=$mysqli->query("select * from order_details where order_id=$order_id");
while($obj=$results->fetch_object())
{           
    $product_name=$obj->product_name;
    $product_code=$obj->product_code;
    $qty=$obj->qty;
    $subtotal=$obj->sub_total;          

    $message .='
    <tr>
        <td>'.$product_name.'</td>
        <td>'.$product_code.'</td>
        <td>'.$qty.'</td>
        <td>'.$subtotal.'</td>
    </tr>';
}

$message .='
</table>';

echo $message;

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: test@gmail.com'."\r\n";
$headers .= "Bcc: $bcc_mail\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

unset($_SESSION['products']);

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this code hope this helps:

```
$result=$mysqli->query("select order_id from orders where user_id='$id' ORDER BY order_id desc limit 1"); 
$obj=$result->fetch_object();
$order_id=$obj->order_id;

$results=$mysqli->query("select * from order_details where order_id=$order_id");

$to="demo@gmail.com";
$bcc_mail="demo@gmail.com";
$subject= "Order Confirmation";

$message .='<table width="100%" border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">

   <tr>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Product Code</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Sub Total</td>
   </tr>';

   while($obj=$results->fetch_object())
   {

    $product_name=$obj->product_name;
    $product_code=$obj->product_code;
    $qty=$obj->qty;
    $subtotal=$obj->sub_total;


$message .= '

    <tr>
        <td>'.$product_name.'</td>
        <td>'.$product_code.'</td>
        <td>'.$qty.'</td>
        <td>'.$subtotal.'</td>
    </tr>';
    }

$message .= '</table>';

echo $message;

$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: test@gmail.com'."\r\n";
$headers .= "Bcc: $bcc_mail\r\n";
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

unset($_SESSION['products']);

?>
```

What I did here is just looping the `tr` which contains data from the db. I haven't tried it though but sure it'll work. Enjoy!